# How to search for name in file and extract value

Tags: java

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Dwarf remains:0
Toolkit:1
Cannonball:2
Nulodion's notes:3
Ammo mould:4
Instruction manual:5
Cannon base:6
Cannon base noted:7
Cannon stand:8
Cannon stand noted:9
Cannon barrels:10
...
```

What is the easiest way to open this file, search for name and return the value of the field? I cannot use any external libraries.

What i have tried/is this ok?

```
    public String item(String name) throws IOException{
    String line;
    FileReader in = new FileReader("C:/test.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);


    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.contains(name)){
            String[] parts = line.split(":");
            return parts[1];
        }
    }

    return null;



}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Any efforts?

Comment: Open the file, read it line by line, use a regex to check for the name and if you found the appropriate line close the file (if needed) and return the value. Classes to look at: `File`, `FileReader`, `BufferedReader` (for easy line reading), `String` (or maybe `Pattern` and `Matcher`), etc.

Comment: simply read the content and find what ever you want...and it would be great if you post the code you have tried or error you facing.

Comment: doesn't sound too difficult, does it?

Comment: You really need to learn to use search engines. Search for "java read file" and you'll find all you need. Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java

Comment: @TobiasR. sorry added now

Comment: @Mohit does the thing i tried look ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a followup to your code - it compiles and works ok. Be aware though, that `/` is not the correct path separator on Windows (`\` is). You could've created the correct path using, for example: `Paths.get("C:", "test.txt").toString()`. Correct separator is defined as well in `File.separator`.

Answer (score 0):

The task can be easily achieved using basic Java capabilities. Firstly, you need to open the the file and read its lines. It can be easily achieved with `Files.lines (Path.get ("path/to/file"))`. Secondly, you need to iterate through all the lines returned by those instructions. If you do not know stream API, you can change value returned from `Files.lines (...)` from `Stream` to an array using `String[] lines =  Files.lines(Paths.get("path/to/file")).toArray(a -> new String[a]);`. Now `lines` variable has all the lines from the input file.

You have to then split each line into two parts (`String.split`) and see whether first part equals (`String.equals`) what you're looking for. Then simply return the second one.